# Can foreign national US residents volunteer with US political campaigns?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance

[This question about *donating* to campaigns as a US resident noncitizen](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42593/contributing-to-a-candidate-as-a-foreign-national-us-resident) led me to wonder if US resident noncitizens/foreign nationals can volunteer with political campaigns in any capacity (direct voter contact or behind the scenes, without payment).

Comment: You have created at least three accounts ([dcacat](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/27161/dcacat), [dcacat](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/27346/dcacat), and [dcacat](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/27398/dcacat)).  You can [merge](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[Wassila Hachchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassila_Hachchi) was a member of the Dutch parliament until January 2016, when she quit her seat in parliament to work for Hillary Clintons election campaign.

She wasn't a US resident, but if non-US, non-residents can, non-US residents can as well.

Comment: Is there a source that confirms she actually did work for the Clinton campaign? All I can find are news articles saying she would do it, and another newspaper report that claims she was looking for a job on the campaign but couldn't find one.